# Custom Suggestions in android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to show custom suggestions in android softkeyboard.For that I am using the below code.
UserDictionary.Words.addWord(getActivity(), newQuery, 254, null, null);
Have also added the permission in manifest.

But still when I type I am not able to see the suggestions above the keyboard.

Thanx

Comment: which permission you have added ?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>

Comment: try to add Locale.getDefault() at last parameter.

Comment: tried still the same problem.

Comment: Just checked all the words are getting stored in database but keyboard is not reading them to show the suggestion.